# NFS Block Size Open File

Tags: filesystems, nfs

If I open an NFS file for the first time, what exactly is it that gets "downloaded"? Is it just file metadata and subsequent client requests will request individual blocks? Is it the whole file, or just the first block? I couldn't find an answer anywhere.